# using vars as numbers in sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep

Having some difficulty in getting a sed | grep pipe to work when using vars as numbers.
In the string below the '3,5p' works fine, but when substituting the numbers for vars I get the error

`sed: -e expression #1, char 4: extra characters after command`

`working=$(sed -n '3,5p'  ${myFile}  | grep -n  "string" |cut -f1 -d: )`

`notWorking=$(sed -n  '${LINESTART},${LINEEND}p'  ${myFile}  | grep -n  "string" |cut -f1 -d: )`

I would also be interested in any advice how I could change command so the line number returned is replaced with $string2 in the file myFile

thanks
Art

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the variables to be expanded by `sed`. For that, you have to enclose the expression within double quotes:

```
sed -n  "${LINESTART},${LINEEND}p"  ${myFile} 
        ^                        ^
```

instead of

```
sed -n  '${LINESTART},${LINEEND}p'  ${myFile}
```

---

As you are checking for the line number in `$myFile` where `string` is found, it line is in between `$LINESTART` and `$LINEEND`, you can do:

```
awk 'NR>=start && NR<=end && /string/ {print NR}' start=$LINESTART end=$LINEEND ${myFile}
```

---

Suppose you want to replace a string just if it appears in specific lines. You can use this:

```
sed -i.bak "$LINESTART,$LINEEND s/FIND/REPLACE/' file
```

- `-i.bak` makes a backup of the file and does an in-place edit: `file` will contain the modified file, while `file.bak` will be the backup.

#### Test

```
$ cat a
hello
this is
something
i want changed
end
but this is not to be changed

$ sed -i.bak '3,5 s/changed/NEW/' a
$ cat a
hello
this is
something
i want NEW      <---- "changed" got replaced
end
but this is not to be changed <---- this "changed" did not
```

Comment: Outstanding for picking up the quotes so fast, will accept as soon as SO will allow me to. thx Art.  PS any advice on how to just replace the string rather than spit out the number and run another line of code to replace?

Comment: @artvanderlay nice :) If you want to replace, you can use `sed -i '...'` See my updated answer.

Comment: +1 for the added detail